In cmake, how to pass multi lists as cmake function args
My code:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.29)

function(my_function)
    cmake_parse_arguments(MY_FUNCTION "" "LIST1;LIST2" "" ${ARGN})

    message("List 1: ${MY_FUNCTION_LIST1}")
    message("List 2: ${MY_FUNCTION_LIST2}")

    # Alternatively, you can access the lists directly without parsing
    foreach(item IN LISTS MY_FUNCTION_LIST1)
        message("Item in List 1: ${item}")
    endforeach()

    foreach(item IN LISTS MY_FUNCTION_LIST2)
        message("Item in List 2: ${item}")
    endforeach()
endfunction()

set(my_list1 "item1;item2;item3")
set(my_list2 "itemA;itemB;itemC")

my_function(LIST1 "${my_list1}" LIST2 "${my_list2}")

I hope pass full my_list1 and full my_list2 to my_function, but message out
List 1: item1
List 2: itemA
Item in List 1: item1
Item in List 2: itemA

it only get list first item, how to pass full list to function

Thank you very much for providing an MRE. The code (post-edit) produces your output exactly when running with cmake -P test.cmake.

You have listed LIST1 and LIST2 as single-parameter arguments in your call to cmake_parse_arguments.
Just change this line:
    cmake_parse_arguments(MY_FUNCTION "" "LIST1;LIST2" "" ${ARGN})

To this:
    cmake_parse_arguments(MY_FUNCTION "" "" "LIST1;LIST2" ${ARGN})

Output:
List 1: item1;item2;item3
List 2: itemA;itemB;itemC
Item in List 1: item1
Item in List 1: item2
Item in List 1: item3
Item in List 2: itemA
Item in List 2: itemB
Item in List 2: itemC

Alternatively, you may use the PARSE_ARGV form of cmake_parse_arguments, like so:
    cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 MY_FUNCTION "" "LIST1;LIST2" "")

This produces the same output as above.
Consult the documentation here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/cmake_parse_arguments.html
